# Calculate limit with squares $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{n^3+2n-1}-\sqrt[3]{n^3+2n-3}\right)^6 \cdot (1+3n+2n^3)^4$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{n^3+2n-1}-\sqrt[3]{n^3+2n-3}\right)^6 \cdot (1+3n+2n^3)^4 $$

What I did was to multiply it and I got $\frac{1}{2}$ as the final result. Could someone confirm if it's correct?

Comment: How did you get $1/2$? I can not see it.

Comment: J.Doe: If you want just verify your result, there are many tools online which work at least for simple limits. For example, [you can try WolframAlfa](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+at+infinity+(%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bn%5E3%2B2n-1%7D-%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bn%5E3%2B2n-3%7D)%5E6*(1%2B3n%2B2n%5E3)%5E4). If you want input from other users from your solution (which lead to result 1/2), you need to include your approach in the quesotin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint:

Since $$a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2},$$ we obtain:
$$\left(\sqrt[3]{n^3+2n-1}-\sqrt{n^3+2n-3}\right)^6(1+3n+2n^3)^4=$$
$$=\left(\tfrac{n^3+2n-1-(n^3+2n-3)}{\sqrt[3]{(n^3+2n-1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(n^3+2n-1)(n^3+2n-3)}+\sqrt[3]{n^3+2n-3)^2}}\right)^6(1+3n+2n^3)^4=$$
$$=\frac{64(1+3n+2n^3)^4}{\left(\sqrt[3]{(n^3+2n-1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(n^3+2n-1)(n^3+2n-3)}+\sqrt[3]{n^3+2n-3)^2}\right)^6}=$$
$$=\frac{64\left(\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{3}{n^2}+2\right)^4}{\left(\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^2}+\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}-\frac{3}{n^3}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}-\frac{3}{n^3}\right)^2}\right)^6}.$$

Comment: So the result is 1024/729?

Comment: @J. Doe Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial expansion or, better, Taylor series to show that
$$\sqrt[3]{n^3+2n-1}=n+\frac{2}{3 n}-\frac{1}{3 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ $$\sqrt[3]{n^3+2n-3}=n+\frac{2}{3 n}-\frac{1}{ n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\sqrt[3]{n^3+2n-1}-\sqrt[3]{n^3+2n-3}=\frac{2}{3 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ The remaining looks to be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)$$